# Stative and Informative sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Are below sentences construction and meanings are correct?

My ID card is damaged in water (Stative Sentence)

Meaning: In above sentence Person want to only convey status of ID card that it is damaged.

My ID card has damaged In water.(Informative Sentence)

Meaning: In Above sentence person want to inform about his ID card that it is damaged in water.

My ID card has been damaged in water. 
Meaning: In above Sentence person want to inform that is ID card is damaged in water form some period of time. i.e. from yesterday till date.

I would like to know more about is and has as auxiliary.

Are below sentence construction are correct.

a) My car has damaged in transit.
b) This tree has fallen in earthquake.
c) Match has cancelled due to rain.
e) My cricket bat has broken in transit.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) My ID card **is** damaged.

This defines the state of the card. But when you add how it was damaged (by water), it changes to past tense:

> My ID card **has/had been** damaged **by** water.

This says *how* the card was damaged (how the state of the card changed).

Usage of *has been* or *had been* depends on when the statement is made relative to the occurrence described.

Your other phrases:

> a) My car **had been** damaged in transit. (When you know this would be after the "transit".)
>   b) This tree **had fallen** in **an** earthquake. (Again its after the earthquake.)
>   c) **The** match **has/had been** cancelled due to rain. (*has* or *had* depending on when the statement was made.)
>   e) My cricket bat **had been** broken in transit. (same as a))

Comment: Thanks for answer. My version "My card has damaged" is corret or not?

Comment: Nope. Here the verb is "has", it is not a helper verb. You could say "My card has damage."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "damaged in water" can not be used as a state.  It is an adverbial phrase.
My ID card is broken.
My ID card is damaged.
My ID card is water damaged.
My ID card will be damaged by water.
My ID card has water damage.

First sentence.
What causes damage to your ID card?
My ID card is damaged in water.  (A bit odd though.)
My ID card is damaged by water.

The meaning.  The card is not damaged now.
My ID card was damaged by water.  Now the card is damaged.

Does your ID card work?
No.  My ID card has water damage.

Comment: Does your ID card work? No. My ID card has water damage. I think it should be "My ID card has a water damage."